# How can I trigger all running non-Windows processes to close?

Tags: windows, process, shutdown, logoff

In Windows, when you choose the Log Off power command, sometimes it will hang on a process and let you cancel logging off. It then takes you back to your desktop, where all processes other than the one that was hanging it has closed.

Is there any command or something I can use to do this manually? Before I launch games, I want all of my applications and extra processes to close, and it takes a very long time to do it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a sleeping / non-running process, then it shouldn't be using any CPU while you play a game anyway, so there might not be a point to closing it (unless it were to free a ton of ram, but if it's sleeping it's ram would likely be cached to the pagefile anyway).

There are some programs/services that tend to "wake up" a lot, and use CPU & internet, that could benefit from being closed - I'm thinking of "quick launch" or "update checkers" that aren't really needed to be running all the time. Finding and **stopping those from running at all** would be more productive.

And, there are often a LOT of sleeping processes that are important to windows, and blindly closing them could be very bad for usability, stability...